# Why is my React Native app crashing on start without any error?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, crash

My React Native app works perfectly fine on the iOS simulator, but does not work when running on my iOS device. It simply shows the splash screen, then crashes without any error.

I have tried:

1. Deleting and reinstalling `node_modules`
2. Deleting iOS build folder
3. Resetting watchman cache with `react-native start --reset-cache`

But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out my issue: my WiFi was being really spotty.

All I had to do was just connect to my mobile hotspot, rebuild, and it works! I think Metro or something else behind the scenes with React Native relies on a stable network.

Hopefully this helps someone else!